# Double dot product in index notation

Tags: notation, tensor-products

How would I write a double dot product in index notation. For example, let $\vec{u} = [u_1,u_2], \vec{v}=[v_1,v_2]$, then

$
\nabla\vec{u}:\nabla\vec{v}=\nabla u_x\cdot\nabla v_x+\nabla u_y\cdot\nabla v_y=
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1}
+
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_2}
+
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_1}
+
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_2}
$

In index notation, I managed to get the first two terms in the right-most part of the equation:

$
\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}
=
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1}
+
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x_2}\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_2}
$

where I have used implicit summation over the repeated index $j$... now that I look at it, it doesn't even seem correct, because there are two repeated indices...

Many thanks.

Comment: When you have $2$ repeated indices you sum over both both of them. So what you wrote (on the LHS) is actually correct.  That is $$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}:= \sum_i \sum_j \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}$$ which has all four terms.

Comment: Ahh, of course. I'm too tired and not too familiar with index notation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. :-)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with stackexchange as well! What's the correct way of closing this question and marking your answer as the taken one? - Since you've replied in the comment section, I'm not sure what to do now.

Comment: I don't think you're able to delete your own questions, yet, since you don't have enough rep.  So I'll just rewrite my comment as an answer and you can accept it from there.  Just click on the checkmark left of the answer (it'll turn green once you do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have $2$ repeated indices you sum over both both of them. So what you wrote (on the LHS) is actually correct. That is
$$\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}:= \sum_i \sum_j \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}$$
which has all four terms.